# SparseArray does not substitute the variables passed to the function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, sparse-matrix

Here is a bit of offending code in Mathematica 13:

```
In[132]:= M[d_] = Normal[SparseArray[{1, 1} -> d]]

Out[132]= {{d}}

In[133]:= M[1]

Out[133]= {{1}}

In[134]:= M[d_] = SparseArray[{1, 1} -> d]

Out[134]= {0}[{d}]

In[136]:= M[1] // Normal

Out[136]= {{d}}
```

Hi,
First line works as expected.
Line [134] does not work as I expected for some reasons... I expected to get {{1}} in line 136.  Very confusing.
Why doen't SparseArray  substitute the value of the function argument when called?
Thank you,
Sergey

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a bug in the scoping of `SparseArray`.  `d` is in there if you look at its down value, but it's not receiving the input `d`.

```
Clear[M]

M[d_] = SparseArray[{1, 1} -> d]

DownValues[M] // InputForm
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[M[d]] :> SparseArray[Automatic,{1,1},0,{1,{{0,1,{{1}}},{d}}]}
> ```

```
M[1] // Normal
```

> ```
> {{d}}
> ```

If you use the more orthodox [`SetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) (:=) there is no problem.

```
Clear[M]

M[d_] := SparseArray[{1, 1} -> d]

DownValues[M] // InputForm
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[M[d]] :> SparseArray[{1, 1} -> d]}
> ```

```
M[1] // Normal
```

> ```
> {{1}}
> ```

Comment: Thank you!  Just a comment that the same issue affects the BlockDiagonalMatrix  function.